# Firepower 10 wwLayoutGrid + MySQL + Delphi - 1st record in all cells

Tags: mysql, delphi

I try use wwLayoutGrid from Firepower 10, all demos work correct, but I try to use in my project Firepower grids, in wwDataGrid all data views correctly and smoothly, but in wwLayoutGrid in each cell view 1st record of my table. 
Used - Delphi 10.1 + Unidac MySQL +  Firepower 10 for delphi 10.1

Layoutgrids don’t work with some data provider? Someone has come across a similar problem?

PS. In design-mode, everything works fine. The problem appears only during run-time.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: I try to make some example, and I find - when data source locate in same form with layoutgrid, all work correct, if data location in datamodule - problem return